# Why is this JavaScript floor math code returning nan?

Tags: javascript, math, floor

```
var num = Math.floor(document.getElementById("num").innerHTML);
document.getElementById("num").innerHTML = num+1;
}
else{
document.getElementById("num").innerHTML = num-1;
}
```

I get $NaN, unfortunately!

The contents of the span is `<span id="num">0</span>`, you know, nothing special, and I must be doing something stupid so I'm utterly confused!

Thank ye.

Comment: Because `innerHTML` is NaN.

Comment: If you are going to post code, it should be valid code...Where is the if? Where does the $ come from?

Comment: Can you throw some `console.log` statements in there to see what you're getting, because there's nothing inherently wrong with what you're doing.  I would do this: `var elt = document.getElementById('num'); console.log( elt ); var numStr = elt.innerHTML; console.log( numStr );`.  Then the answer should become clear.

Comment: Here's the [full code](http://codepad.org/ZXNcZuqc)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And your full code shows why -1 does not work

```
if (document.getElementById("div").style.top === "40px") {
    var num = Math.floor(document.getElementById("num").innerHTML);
    document.getElementById("num").innerHTML = num + 1;
} else {
    document.getElementById("num").innerHTML = num - 1;
}
```

So what is `undefined - 1`? Well it is `NaN`! Why? because `num` is set in the if, not the else.

How do you fix it? Move the `var num` line outside of the if!

Answer (score 0):

`.innerHTML` returns a string. Strings can't be `.floor`ed. You'll have to `parseInt()` first.

Comment: but then why do I only get $NaN on the -1 part? I forgot to say in the original question, but num+1 worked!

Comment: I just tried `parseInt(document.getElementById("num").innerHTML);`. But it still returns NaN.

Comment: so don't chain the calls and start checking individual elements. `x = document.getElementById('num')`. does that return anything? `y = x.innerHTML`, does that return anything, etc...

Comment: Incorrect.  JavaScript does automatic conversion in this case; you do not need to call `parseInt()` first.  Enter the following in a JavaScript console: `Math.floor(7.3)` (yields 7) then `Math.floor('7.3')` (also yields 7).

Comment: Thats what I thought @EthanBrown, but so what should I do to fix the nan problem?

Comment: See my comment above.  `console.log` is your friend.

Answer (score 0):

The shown code is incomplete and makes it impossible to track. But I'm assuming that the NaN is being passed to Floor() to begin with. Pass a valid number/numeric string to floor() to make it work. Error is in the logic of code not shown in the question.

EDIT:

After looking at your code it's clear that the problem is due to a misplaced assignment operation. If the 'if' part is called, everything is fine, but if the 'else' part is called, 'num' is never created or assigned a value, causing it to be NaN. To fix this issue I'd recommend doing this:

Change this:

```
if(document.getElementById("div").style.top === "40px"){
    var num = Math.floor(document.getElementById("num").innerHTML);
    document.getElementById("num").innerHTML = num+1;
}
else{
    document.getElementById("num").innerHTML = num-1;
}
```

To this:

```
var num = Math.floor(document.getElementById("num").innerHTML);
if(document.getElementById("div").style.top === "40px"){
    document.getElementById("num").innerHTML = num+1;
}
else{
    document.getElementById("num").innerHTML = num-1;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I've edited my answer to include the problem and it's fix.